# Change formlyConfig to allow reselecting an empty option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-formly

I have this custom select in formlyConfig but once the any other option than empty (blank) is selected it disappears from the list. Is there a way to edit this formlyConfig to allow empty option to be selected again and not disappear from the list?

This is the config

```
formlyConfig.setType({
    name: 'select2',
    template: '<select class="form-control" ng-model="model[options.key]"></select><div class="div-after-select"></div>',
    wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError'],
    defaultOptions: function defaultOptions(options) {
        /* jshint maxlen:195 */
        var ngOptions = options.templateOptions.ngOptions || 'option[to.valueProp || \'value\'] as option[to.labelProp || \'name\'] group by option[to.groupProp || \'group\'] for option in to.options';
        return {
            ngModelAttrs: _defineProperty({}, ngOptions, {
                value: options.templateOptions.optionsAttr || 'ng-options'
            })
        };
    },
    apiCheck: function apiCheck(check) {
        return {
            templateOptions: {
                options: check.arrayOf(check.object),
                optionsAttr: check.string.optional,
                labelProp: check.string.optional,
                valueProp: check.string.optional,
                groupProp: check.string.optional
            }
        };
    }
});
```

As you can see once I've picked 'Ms' and there is no empty option anymore. It's been there before.
[image]

Comment: I have added this to the template and it works: <option ng-hide="to.notNull" value="">{{to.nullDisplay}}</option>

Comment: Any idea how to make this empty value appear only if the field required=false?

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask but I assume there hasn't been added a "simple" way of doing this yet, has it?

For future readers: one way you can most certainly achieve this, though it is a bit of a pain, is by using custom templates (https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field). This is a replacement for using the `template` property used above. Within the template you can access all the config attributes over the `to` attribute, that your custom template component will inherit from formly's `FieldType` class. This way you can also access the `required` property and more